# React | Build file shows blank

Tags: reactjs

Iam trying to build and deploy react app .
I have executed build , if open index.html file from build folder[!PFB screenshot] open as blank.
I have added "homepage": "./", in package.json that also not working.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

hay. I was also facing the same problem.I just tried to figure out why its happening.I tried every thing step by step and found that when I try to replace favicon.ico that we get in public folder with some other ico file with same name. we get build index.html as blank white..
even after i tried to replace back the file with original i still get the same blank page..
so as a conclusion you might have misplayed with public folder...